# I want to set IE as default browser in windows 10 by vb.net code or any exe. I have used below VBS script. But it is not working

Tags: vbscript, exe

I have tried below script but not working. If it run manually, focus is correct. But if it is run through registry it is not taking focus to desired window. U can also suggest me if there is any other way to keep focus on desired window. The window opened through this code is control panel settig window and it is not found under proccess in task magager.
So please give solution.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name 
Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?
pszAppName=Internet%20Explorer"

'Give Default Programs time to load 

WScript.Sleep 500

WshShell.AppActivate "Set Program Associations"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "

Msgbox "Default Browser: Internet Explorer"

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: I think the simpler way would be with registry: [reg list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/aa3a1535-aa86-4afe-9fa2-c6345682efc9/registry-key-for-default-browser?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) and also [MSDN Default Browser Shell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224816/use-shellexecute-to-launch-the-default-web-browser)

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.  VBScript is not the same thing as VB.Net.  I have changed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Set-IEAsDefaultBrowser {
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
Start-Process $env:windir\system32\control.exe -ArgumentList '/name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Internet%20Explorer'
Sleep 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB} {TAB}{TAB} ")
}
Set-IEAsDefaultBrowser
```

I tried to run this script in windows powershell for set Internet Explorer as default Browser. It's works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Internet%20Explorer"
WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
Msgbox "Default Browser: Internet Explorer"
WScript.Quit
```

it works fine for me.